# Rstudio : Library conflict with Keras and h5 package

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have made a CPU based quick install of Keras for R in Rstudio.

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

From this point everythink were installed successfully, I decided to follow the Pre-trained Model Resnet50 example (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/articles/applications.html). I have download the Resnet50 model locally which is a h5 file. I have installed in Rstudio the cran package h5 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h5/index.html) so I can read the h5 format.

```
library(h5)
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

# instantiate the model
model <- h5file("./Data/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5", 'a')

# load the image
img_path <- "./Images/Bird.jpg"
img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(640,571))
x <- image_to_array(img)

# ensure we have a 4d tensor with single element in the batch dimension,
# the preprocess the input for prediction using resnet50
x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
x <- imagenet_preprocess_input(x)


# make predictions then decode and print them
preds <- model %>% predict(x)
imagenet_decode_predictions(preds, top = 3)[[1]]
```

I have gotten an error here:

```
preds <- model %>% predict(x)

no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('H5File', 'CommonFG', 'H5Location')
```

It seem that the predict() function used is from the package "h5" but i want to use predict() function from the package "stats" that was installed by Keras.

So I have tried:

```
preds <- model %>% stats::predict(x)
```

But I still get the same error, the predict() function used is still from the package h5.

Does anyone know why, please ?

Best regards.

Comment: your `model` is still an `H5File`. I suppose you need to extract a particular dataset from it, see e.g. `list.datasets(model, recursive = TRUE)`